# Google Analytics of Blogger site (with Content Warning)

Tags: google-analytics, google-adsense, blogger

I have applied the following Google services to my Blogger site (with Content Warning enabled):

- Google Analytics
- Google AdSense

However, I cannot obtain 2 sets of web statistics data from Blogger's Statistics tab, Analytics, and AdSense. Google Analytics receive "Access Denied" warning in In-Page Analysis too.

Example:

- Blogger's Statistics tab shows 88 visits per day
- Google Analytics show 0 visit per day (Note 1)
- Google AdSense show 0 visit per day (Note 1)

All are Google's service, but why am I receiving different data? Also, AdSense is not gaining money but the ads are showing up in my blog.

**Note 1:** I have set up URL Channel in AdSense & Analytics, but no data is shown.

p.s. Google Analytics status is "Receiving Data", and it does record visits on the first day when the blog is using traditional layout. Blogger site is now using "Dynamic layout".

Comment: How long ago did you install Google Analytics tracking script?

Comment: The site has been set up for 1 week, and GA tracking ID is entered into Blogger from Day 1.

Comment: What's the URL please?

Comment: You did not say it was an adult site...? You can't run AdSense on sites of adult nature. Check against your Analytics account, is the profile ID UA-40934413-2 (actually confirm that the tracking code in your Google Analytics account for this specific profile display that)?

Comment: yes, the profile ID is correct, but neither AdSense / Analytics show warning / error on the contents...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I disabled the content warning, Google Analytics and Google AdSense work again.

Seems Google has blocked Google Analytics & AdSense servicing on sensitive contents.